# How to point rpy2 to existing R installation?

Tags: r, rpy2

I have two installations of R. Is there a way to explicitly point rpy2 to one of these?

Comment: i have no idea how rpy2 works, but i assume it uses R by console access, and the version it finds is the one in your PATH variable... if so you might have to manipulate that... but that would be a very ugly solution :)

Comment: It does use the PATH. I guess that @phonixor is writing all his command lines in a shell/terminal with explicit absolute paths because because of that ugly shell feature that makes it search executable in the PATH ;-)

Comment: no, the ugly part is that if your program is not using your systems default R, your program has to modify the PATH before launch, and restore it after :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe @phonixor is right. rpy2 uses the R it finds in the path. If you want to change that, change your path.

```
PATH=/path/to/r/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: on windows, you have to set `RPATH` and `RHOME` environment variables, I believe. (working from memory and it's been a while).